# Maintaining an open Redis PubSub subscription with Booksleeve

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redis, booksleeve

I am using a Redis pubsub channel to send messages from a pool of worker processes to my ASP.NET application. When a message is received, my application forwards the message to a client's browser with SignalR.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777999/145831) to maintaining an open connection to Redis, but it doesn't account for subscriptions when it recreates the connection.

I'm currently handling Redis pubsub messages in my Global.asax file:

```
public class Application : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var gateway = Resolve<RedisConnectionGateway>();
        var connection = gateway.GetConnection();
        var channel = connection.GetOpenSubscriberChannel();

        channel.PatternSubscribe("workers:job-done:*", OnExecutionCompleted);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle messages received from workers through Redis.</summary>
    private static void OnExecutionCompleted(string key, byte[] message)
    {
        /* forwarded the response to the client that requested it */
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the current RedisConnection is closed for whatever reason. The simplest solution the problem would be to fire an event from the `RedisConnectionGateway` class when the connection has been reset, and resubscribe using a new `RedisSubscriberChannel`. However, any messages published to the channel while the connection is being reset would be lost.

Are there any examples of recommended ways to handle this situation?

Comment: My solution indeed returns a Redis connection if it's open already, or opens one if not. I believe that in "conventional use" the connection will remain open and you won't get it dropped in your PubSub schema. In the rare case of the connection being closed from some reason, you will get a new one, and yes - messages published to the channel while the connection is being reset would be lost. But it's for a very short time, and it doesn't suppose to happen on a regular basis. Anyway, let's have BookSleeve's author highlight on this (CC @marcgravell).

Comment: @OferZelig thanks, but `@someone` doesn't work unless I'm already involved in the post somehow ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't know that; anyway: 1) How can one communicate with another SE user to get his/her attention to something? I mean - inside an SE site, not by checking is profile and go to his/her blog or such; 2) You can implement in SE a feature that identifies this and alerts (an <at>xxx pattern, where xxx is a known SE user name). Thanks!

Comment: SE display-names are not enforced as unique. By design, you can only use `@username` to engage people already involved in a question. In SO, the post is the important unit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if the connection dies (network instability, re-mastering, whatever) then you will need to re-apply any subscriptions you have made. An event to reconnect and resubscribe is pretty normal, and not very different to what we use here on SE/SO (except we typically track more granular subscriptions, and have some wrapper code that handles all that).

Yes, any events published while your connection was broken are gone. That is the nature of redis pub/sub; it does not guarantee delivery to disconnected clients. Either use a tool that *does* promise this, or use redis to drive a queue instead - pushing/popping to/from opposite ends of a list is usually a reasonable alternative, and ensures nothing is lost (as long as your software doesn't drop it after popping it from the list). If it helps, I have on my list a request to add the blocking pop methods - they totally destroy the multiplexer intent, but they have genuine use in some cases, so I'm not against adding them.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing the blocking pop methods added to the API. Right now my web project is using Booksleeve, but workers that service my web app depend on ServiceStack.Redis for the blocking pop API.

Comment: @Justin it shall be added - hopefully this week

Comment: That would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @MarcGravell is it still relevant ? After some testing ("clinet kill type pubsub", "client publish") it seems that SE.Redis resubscribe to the event after a reconnection, can you confirm ?

Comment: What about .net core web api, how to keep the subscriber running forever?