# Redis Server and connecting with multiple clients

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, redis

I have a single Redis server running on a Windows 2008 machine.  I have multiple websites that each use the `BasicRedisClientManager.` This instance is setup once on app start and set in into the `Application[]` store. That way it's reusable across all users. The problem I am having is that one site runs on a dedicated server and the other sites run on localhost where the Redis server is running. One is production and the others are test locations for new work/demonstration. The remote client works just fine but the localhost clients will not communicate with the server and seem to be in a locked/dead state. When I run the site I just get a stack overflow and the site recycles itself.  Below is some sample code of the setup I have. I see there is some information on creating locks amongst clients but I'm not sure if this is the route I need to take.

http://www.servicestack.net/docs/redis-client/distributed-locking-with-redis

Sample Code:

```
    protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * Create basicRedisClientManager for redis.
         */
        var redisHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisHostIp"].ToString();
        BasicRedisClientManager basicRedisClientManager = new BasicRedisClientManager(redisHost);
        Application["BasicRedisClientManager"] = basicRedisClientManager;

     .....
    }
```

Then it's use in class constructor

```
    public CacheManager()
    {
        if (Application["BasicRedisClientManager"] != null)
        {
            /*local variable*/
            basicRedisClientManager = (BasicRedisClientManager)Application["BasicRedisClientManager"];
        }
    }
```

Within class using the manager.

```
        if (basicRedisClientManager != null)
        {
            using (var redisClient = (RedisClient)basicRedisClientManager.GetClient())
            {
                if (!saveToInProcOnly && redisClient != null)
                {
                    using (var redis = redisClient.GetTypedClient<T>())
                    {
                        redis.SetEntry(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This logic is the same across all sites.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `BasicRedisClientManager` but I recommend you to use [BookSleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) client library. With regards to connection reuse, the answer is don't reuse. That is, recreate the connection every time you need it, as BookSleeve's author recommends.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645953/maintaining-an-open-redis-connection-using-booksleeve) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777999/290343) to see how to create bullet-proof Redis client connection.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but we cannot use book sleeve as it requires .net4.  I have to believe that there is an answer to this other than just use book sleeve.  Am i not implementing it right to connect to Redis from multiple websites? I would think a new client would spin up from my second site instance and use that client for communication.