# Can Redis be run in-process w/.net?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to run Redis in process under .NET?

I understand the general use case is for Redis is out of process, and likely on another server. The app I'm working on has needs for both in-process caching and out of process caching. My thinking here is that I would like to use the same  app/library for both the in process and out of process needs.

Comment: No. There is no support for an in-process API with Redis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You should use `Cache` or alike in-process.

But you are definitely on the right track, doing 2 level caching (L1+L2). Stack Exchange themselves do so. See for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478883/290343
- http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html